# Vega editor "table is empty"

Tags: javascript, vega-lite

I am trying to build an elementary plot showing proportion of energy source by continent. I've already cleaned up the data and uploaded a .csv file here : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mkeutgen/dataviz_energy/main/prop_source_by_continent_2015
Yet when I try to import it in vega lite editor, it states that my csv is empty.

Here is the code I've written :

```
{
  "data": {"url": "raw.githubusercontent.com/mkeutgen/dataviz_energy/main/prop_source_by_continent_2015"},
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "continent",
      "type": "nominal",
      "domain":["Africa","Europe","Asia","North America","South America","Asia"],
      "title": "Continent"
    },
    "y": {
      "field":"prop",
      "aggregate":"sum",
      "type": "quantitative",
        "stack":  "normalize"
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "share energy",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {
        "domain": ["coal_share_energy","gas_share_energy","nuclear_share_energy",                                       "hydro_share_energy","renewables_share_energy","oil_share_energy"],
        "range": ["#e7ba52", "#c7c7c7", "#aec7e8", "#1f77b4", "#9467bd"]
      },
      "title": "Weather type"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the Javascript console, you'll see the issue:

```
loader.js:175 GET https://vega.github.io/editor/raw.githubusercontent.com/mkeutgen/dataviz_energy/main/prop_source_by_continent_2015 404
```

You are attempting to load the dataset with a relative rather than absolute URL, which is returning a 404; you can fix this by adding `https://` to the front of your URL.

Additionally, since your URL does not include a file extension, you must tell Vega-Lite that the data is CSV-formatted using a `format` specification. With these two changes, your chart works ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA28QAspQA4Gc4B6I5CAdwDoBzASyk0QCNF8BTZAYwHsA7KNv0o8AtkREBrNoijVBRSDAButAF4B9QR2oBPcRHwDkRXMm651+bik5t1THep79avQVHUAmAAwBGAKwgADQgAGbcyCLQ8KBQOrhsGJz4SiAAvmkhUcgSGEwQyMEggjxgrtQxIAAelaG0bKhgSXxQru5FcQkYvNwirhDoIWC9EK7wANogAIKhyLScsCEAoijmiSFT+LSLIAByEQwABFMiHPM7AMrWRydnC0Wb2yAAuiGtUKiJcCAAwi1t-HSIR0tXqjQwpnMRQg1GoyDY1GgXxA+EQIg68WRAEdEBAXDBWkp1iiYJxct8epEBmpEpkQDxUBFQQ0mt98JgCmxDlpkLoMV0Kb1+oMUQtPpVhlExnBJjwBpYOfDNG5eSCQoj8ArOcrtGqQLxEJxPgUtUqeXyQpgdGAzKa7Oa9fC3OQIExPpr2dqHUVuLRUHadaqXiEyLw5BMQABiNgAdny-k8RUjnBjKZTSYgbBTbAAHEnfKEY3GACxJgCcxYAbHGms86e9xd8AOpsaCYDiHTq0jJAA)):

```json
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mkeutgen/dataviz_energy/master/prop_source_by_continent_2015",
    "format": {"type": "csv"}
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "continent",
      "type": "nominal",
      "domain":["Africa","Europe","Asia","North America","South America","Asia"],
      "title": "Continent"
    },
    "y": {
      "field":"prop",
      "aggregate":"sum",
      "type": "quantitative",
        "stack":  "normalize"
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "share energy",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {
        "domain": ["coal_share_energy","gas_share_energy","nuclear_share_energy",
                   "hydro_share_energy","renewables_share_energy","oil_share_energy"],
        "range": ["#e7ba52", "#c7c7c7", "#aec7e8", "#1f77b4", "#9467bd"]
      },
      "title": "Weather type"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Url you have provided in your `data` config should also contain `https://` and then need to specify the `format` of data. Refer the below config or try [fiddle](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA28QAspQA4Gc4B6I5CAdwDoBzASyk0QCNF8BTZAYwHsA7KNv0o8AtkREBrNoijVBRSDAButAF4B9QR2oBPcRFq8iuZN1zr83FJzbqmO9T36HBUdQCYADAEYArCAAaEAAzbmQRaHhQKB1cNgxOfCUQAF8UoIASfE5MNgiMbDxCEiU2aggaekYmSlpuImzciKJS8oBaVHo2Ft9KACtLXkCQCOQJDCYIZGHBHjBDaiiQAA8l4No2VDAEvigXfmGYuIxebhFDCHQgsDODIbgAbRAAQWDkWk5YIIBRFDN4oLPfC0L4gAByYQYAAJniIOB9QQBlKzQ2Hwz7DIEgkAAXSCeygqHicBAAGFdvsoKkgjo1hsthgTGZhhBqNRkGVoMSQPhECJDrFuQBHRAQZwwPalYb4GCccYk07hS5qeLpEA8VBhOmbbYk-CYKZsKFaZC6AXHBVnC5XHmfIlLG4RQzwJ48S4WA0czS8bS0oLlfAew3e33DXiIThEqZBr0ms1BTA6MCmGO2ON+kAcn3kCBMImB-XB9PDbi0VCpkOm2l4zNiuQukAAYjYAHZJr53MNG5wWz2e12IGwe2wABxd7zBFttgAsXYAnNOAGxt7Y4tUE+0kgDqbGguWQUKOqrSQA):

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mkeutgen/dataviz_energy/main/prop_source_by_continent_2015",
    "format": {"type": "csv"}
  },
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "continent",
      "type": "nominal",
      "domain": [
        "Africa",
        "Europe",
        "Asia",
        "North America",
        "South America",
        "Asia"
      ],
      "title": "Continent"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "prop",
      "aggregate": "sum",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "stack": "normalize"
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "share energy",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {
        "domain": [
          "coal_share_energy",
          "gas_share_energy",
          "nuclear_share_energy",
          "hydro_share_energy",
          "renewables_share_energy",
          "oil_share_energy"
        ],
        "range": ["#e7ba52", "#c7c7c7", "#aec7e8", "#1f77b4", "#9467bd"]
      },
      "title": "Weather type"
    }
  }
}
```